# Object array in FormData passing 0 objects to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm making an ajax call to the controller passing the FormData(), which has an array of objects along with few other properties. In my controller, the list array which I'm passing seems to have 0 elements. Please help!

Script in cshtml view -

```
    var _getFormDataToJson = function () {                            
            var applyDetail = [];
            $(_tb).find('tbody tr').each(function (i, v) {
                var trans = {
                    effectiveDate: $(this).find('.effectiveDate').val(),
                    amount: $(this).find('.amount').val(),
                    empLeaveHdID: $('#tx-leaveHdID').val(),
                    //attachmentUrl: $(this).find('.leaveAttachment')[0].files[0]
                }

                applyDetail.push(trans);
            });

            var formObj = new FormData();
            formObj.append('remark', $('#tx-remark').val());
            formObj.append('leaveAppType', $('#hdnLeaveAppType').val());
            formObj.append('applyDetail', applyDetail); //this collection has 0 items in controller

            return formObj;
        }

        var _sumbitForm = function () {
            var formData2 = _getFormDataToJson();               
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ApplyLeave", "Leave")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: formData2,
                    //data: { data: formData2 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            _myToastr.success(data.msg[0], true, function () {
                                location.reload();
                            });

                            $(_modal).modal('close');
                        }
                        else {
                            _myToastr.error(data.msg[0]);
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {

                    }
                });
            }
```

Controller -

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ApplyLeave(Hr_LeaveApplyHd data)
    {
        foreach (var detail in data.applyDetail) //applyDetail count is 0 here
        {
            //to DO:
        }

        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

EDIT:
Hr_LeaveApplyHd model -

```
public class Hr_LeaveApplyHd
{
    public Hr_LeaveApplyHd()
    {
        applyDetail = new List<ApplyDetail>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int applyID { get; set; }
    public string remark { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ApplyDetail> applyDetail { get; set; }
    public LeaveAppType leaveAppType { get; set; }
}
```

applyDetail model -

```
public class ApplyDetail 
{
    [Key]
    public int applyDetialID { get; set; }

    public DateTime effectiveDate { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }

    public int empLeaveHdID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try console.log(applyDetail);
And see what is happening?

Comment: What is _tb, id or class?

Comment: @akbansa var _tb = $('#tb-leaveTrans') - id

Comment: Try console.log(applyDetail)

Comment: @akbansa I has an obj array - {effectiveDate: "2017/09/12", amount: "1", empLeaveHdID: "56"}

Comment: You cannot append an array of complex objects to form data - you need to append each individual name/value pair of each item in the array. You have not shown your models so we cannot show you how it needs to be done

Comment: But you could do this in one simple line of code - `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));` is your form is generated correctly in the first place

Comment: @StephenMuecke Have added the model. Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot append arrays and/or complex objects to `FormData`. You need to append name/value pairs for each property of `ApplyDetail` and for each item in the collection, and with indexers, for example

```
formObj .append('applyDetail[0].effectiveDate', '09/19/2017');
```

which you could do in your `$.each` loop, for example

```
var formObj = new FormData();
formObj.append('remark', $('#tx-remark').val());
formObj.append('leaveAppType', $('#hdnLeaveAppType').val());
$(_tb).find('tbody tr').each(function (i, v) {
    var name = 'applyDetail[' + i + '].effectiveDate';
    var value = $(this).find('.effectiveDate').val();
    formObj.append(name, value);
    ... // ditto for other properties
});
```

However, if you have generated your form correctly using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods, including generating the controls for the collection property using a `for` loop of `EditorTemplate` for typeof `ApplyDetail` so they have the correct name attributes to match your model, then all you need is

```
var formObj = new FormData($('form').get(0));
```

which will correctly serialize all the form controls

Comment: Yes! This is the trick to get a complex object into ASP.Net!
Thank You!